# Why Breadth First Search is used for shortest path

Tags: algorithms, graphs, breadth-first-search

We can read on the internet: `BFS finds the shortest path to the destination.`

But how ? Check this example:

[image]

for this example we can get 40 10 20 30 60 50 70

What is going on here ?
In my opinion the shortest way to 50 is 40 - 20 - 50 so this algorithm is not good for shortest path.

Could someone explain how this algorithm shows the shortest path ?

Comment: Difficult, with *values on nodes* instead of *costs on edges*. All pairs shortest paths? If not, a source and a destination would be useful, even using the graph dual to the one presented.

Comment: *Just how* do you get `60 50 70`?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm produces a tree. To get the shortest path from the source node (node $40$ in this case), to some other node of your choice (node $50$ for example), follow the path in the tree between the two nodes.

Here, the path will indeed be $40\rightarrow 20\rightarrow 50$. Try to construct the BFS tree and see for yourself that this is the case

Comment: 'follow the path in the tree between the two nodes.'  so before all calculation I have map this graph to tree ? or after calculation ?

Comment: The definition of the BFS algorithm creates a tree. In the tree, there will be an edge $(v,u)$ if you "found" $u$ through the node $v$.

Comment: BFS can be used for tree but also a graph, and this case is a graph. So it is not possible to get the shortest way for graph only for a tree ?

Comment: The BFS algorithm creates a sub-tree from the graph. I just described how this tree is generated